# Shuffle the results coming back from getItemsByCAMLQuery

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, pnp-js

In my SPFx web part below I get items from a list.
That works fine.

What is the best way to randomise the results that come back?

I tried to do
r = r.shuffle();
but I think I am way off.

Thanks
P

```
        if(typeof this.properties.filterByPosition !='undefined' && this.properties.filterByPosition)
          camlQuery += "<And>";

        camlQuery += "<Eq><FieldRef Name='department'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>" + this.properties.groupName + "</Value></Eq>";

        if(typeof this.properties.filterByPosition !='undefined' && this.properties.filterByPosition)
          camlQuery += "<Eq><FieldRef Name='jobTitle'></FieldRef><Value Type='Text'>" + this.properties.filterByPosition + "</Value></Eq>";

        if(typeof this.properties.filterByPosition !='undefined' && this.properties.filterByPosition)
          camlQuery += "</And>";

        camlQuery += "</Where></Query></View>";



        //if(typeof this.properties.filterByPosition !='undefined' && this.properties.filterByPosition)

        const r = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("UserData").getItemsByCAMLQuery({
          
            ViewXml: camlQuery,
        });
```

Comment: Are you trying to shuffle array of items based on any specific property?

Comment: I'm just trying to shuffle them randomly. Thanks @GaneshSanap

Comment: Try my answer given below. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [_.shuffle function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle) available in lodash library.

For example:

```
const r = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("UserData").getItemsByCAMLQuery({
    ViewXml: camlQuery,
}); 
const shuffledResponse: any = _.shuffle(r);
```

You can also find other methods for same at: [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array/18650169#18650169)

---

You have to install lodash library using `npm i lodash` and then import it at the top of your file before using it:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

Comment: Thanks @Ganesh I did add lodash via npm. Now I get ... '_' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.